Nemytskij operator for Lebesgue variable UNBOUNDED exponent spaces
Let $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a Caratheodory function (i.e. $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for a.a. $x\in\Omega$ and $f(\cdot,t)$ is measurable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$), where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded domain.
Consider a measurable exponent function $p:\Omega\to (1,\infty)$ that is unbounded, i.e. $(p^+=\infty)$. We assume that the Nemytskii operator $\mathcal{N}_f$ takes every function $u\in L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$ to $\mathcal{N}_f(u)=f(\cdot,u(\cdot))\in L^{p'(x)}(\Omega)$, where $p'(x)=\dfrac{p(x)}{p(x)-1}$.
Questions:
(1) Is $\mathcal{N}_f$ a nonlinear bounded operator? (it takes bounded sets into bounded sets)
(2) Is $\mathcal{N}_f$ continuous from $L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$ to $L^{p'(x)}(\Omega)$?
(3) Our assumption imply a growth condition of $f$? Something like:
$$|f(x,s)|\leq g(x)+c|s|^{p(x)-1}$$
where $g\in L^{p'(x)}(\Omega)$?
If $p$ is a constant exponent then all is known from the article of Goldberg: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/mana.19921550110
If $p\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ then it is also all known from the article of Kovacik and Rakosnik (1991) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274052040_O_Kovacik_J_Rakosnik_On_the_spaces_Lpx_and_Wkpx
It is also known from the book of Cruz-Uribe: Variable exponent spaces that if the exponent $p$ is unbounded the space $L^{p(x)}(\Omega)$
Probably the answer is NO to some if not all of these questions, but I wasn't able to find a counterexample. A counterexample would be excelent.
It seems to me (searching many articles on the internet about variable exponent spaces) that this subject was never studied...

Did you see A nonlinear operator on Orlicz space? Unfortunately the original paper is in Russian but the summary on Zentralblatt seems relevant. I am not sure whether the setting implicitly requires $p$ to be bounded though.

Thank you very much for this reference.
